# Opening an outside project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

So a project I created on textPad, I want to now open it in Eclipse but it will not let me import this project. It is a .java file so I don't understand why it will not open.

Comment: Hi @DakotaRealms, Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page have an understanding of the guidelines on asking good questions.

Comment: Did you use _File > Open Projects from File System..._? What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It is a little cumbersome to import such a "project", but first "File >> New >> Java Project"
[image: File >> New >> Java Project]

Then "File >> Import"

[image: File >> Import]

Then "General / Filesystem"

[image: General / Filesystem]

Then select and import your file(s); make sure you specify into "$PROJECT/src"

[image: Select your files and import]

When done the file should be imported into your eclipse Java project

[image: File imported into eclipse project]

Comment: What about that Projects from Folder or Archive option?

Comment: @nitind That's for existing eclipse project files (and I think zips). The reason this is so difficult; eclipse manages its' own *virtual (**versioned**) file system*.